# In SQLite how do I write a query to find different columns across rows that are equal to each other?

Tags: sql, ubuntu, sqlite

I have a very simple problem I can't wrap my head around in regards to SQLite. I am trying to learn more about SQL by [reading through a book](http://sql.learncodethehardway.com) and following the examples. One of the exercises is to write a query that can find which pet out of a pet table is the parent of another pet. Both the pet.id and pet.parent columns use INTEGER data types. So for one pet the id would be 2 and another pet would be 3... The pet schema has pet (id, name, breed, parent); type of structure. So for example: `INSERT INTO pet VALUES(2, "scraps", "lolcat", 3);`
would make this pet.id=2,pets.name=scraps,pet.breed=lolcat, pet.parent=3. In this table some of the pets will also be parents of other pets. So their pet.id would also match the parent.id of some other pet...(It seems kinda complex)

I wrote a query that I thought makes since but it does not return any results or throw any errors. That query is: 
       `SELECT pet.name, pet.breed FROM pet WHERE
    pet.parent = pet.id;`

Comment: HINT:  you query correctly finds that no animal is its own parent.  You need to do a join.

Comment: Hmm but joins have not been introduced in the book yet @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you know of another way without a JOIN? Thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand how the logic is looking for a pet that is its own parent... 0_o

Comment: All methods use a join.  In this case, you can express the join explicitly in the `from` clause or using an `in` or `=` with a subquery in the `where` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `SELECT pet.name, pet.id, pet.breed, pet.parent FROM pet WHERE pet.parent >= 0;` i thin solves this one...your response is way more advanced that my current SQLite skill-level, but thanks for replying. :D It is just that my brain may fall apart thinking about this too hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [exercise 13](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex13.html): it actually says:

> Write a query that can find the pets that are children of a given pet.

So you have *one specific* parent pet, and its ID, and you are searching for all pets that have that ID as their `parent` ID:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE parent = 3
```

---

To find out all pets in child/parent relationships, you have to do a query that involves *two different* pets at the same time; this requires a **join**.
In this case, there is the additional wrinkle that these records come from the *same* table, so it is necessary to use aliases (`AS`) to rename one or both tables so that we can address their columns unambiguously:

```
SELECT parent.name,
       parent.breed,
       child.name,
       child.breed
FROM      pet AS parent
     JOIN pet AS child
     ON parent.id = child.parent
WHERE ...    -- if needed
```

Comment: JOIN keyword and AS keyword have not been introduced yet @CL. Is there another way?

Comment: and yes it is excercise 13 - The Assignment :D @CL. Awesome job deducing that.

Comment: You have been asking a different question.